# Knowledgebase faq fallback issue google dialogflow

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I have set a default fallback intent which is triggered for all the questions that are designed as intents but for the knowledgebase questions fallback, intent is not getting triggered.

It just shows no answer present.

[image: FAQ Knowledgebase]

[image: Fallback Intent]

I want to know if I have set classification threshold value to 0.8 how are some of the faq intents triggered with 0.5 accuracy

Comment: Can you show how you have set up the fallback intent? Can you show instances where fallback intent is triggered along with the setup of those intents? Can you also show the setup of your knowledge base and the scenario where fallbakc intent is not triggered? See [guide on creating a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you show a sample run when you provided your bot a value and did not show any answer? Also can you show a sample run where your bot is able to respond using the knowledge base?